How to solve $2xy\frac{dy}{dx}+(1+x)y^2=e^x$?
$2xy\frac{dy}{dx}+(1+x)y^2=e^x,\qquad y(1)=\sqrt{\frac{e^2+2}{2e}}$
Performing the substitution $y(x) = (z(x))^{1/2}$ what is the general solution and what is the value of $y(2)$
After doing some calculus I arrive to that final expression

I'm guess I'm doing something wrong because the expression seems too complicated to integrate

Please type out your efforts: It is very difficult to observe your efforts through the image provided. You are less likely to receive a response if you don't do so, as images are generally disliked being the main part of the question for a multitude of reasons on this site.

Your solution isn't entirely legible, but it looks like at some point you're separating variables. The ODE in $z$ is not separable. (And why the change from $x$ to $u$?)

The equation can be multiplied by $\mathrm{e}^{x}$ to become $$2x\mathrm{e}^{x}y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+(1+x)\mathrm{e}^{x}y^2=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\mathrm{e}^xy^2\right)=\mathrm{e}^{2x}$$
By integrating both sides with respect to $x$ we get $$x\mathrm{e}^xy^2=\frac12\mathrm{e}^{2x}+C$$When $x=1$, $y=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{e}^2+2}{2\mathrm{e}}}$, so $$\frac{\mathrm{e}\left(\mathrm{e}^2+2\right)}{2\mathrm{e}}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^2}2+C$$so $C=1$. Rearranging the equation we get $$y^2=\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{2x}+\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{x}\Rightarrow y=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{2x}+\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{x}}$$Substituting $x=2$ gives $$y(2)=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{e}^2}4+\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-2}}2}=\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{e}^4+2}{4\mathrm{e}^2}}$$

thanks but d/dx (x*(e^x)(y^2)) = (1+x)(e^x)*(y^2) right ? you didnt use that expression in your resolution @Sai Mehta

No, from the product and chain rules, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\mathrm{e}^xy^2\right)=2x\mathrm{e}^xy\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+(1+x)\mathrm{e}^xy^2$$
